# Python 'for' loop and append 'list'

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Following code snippet appends only the latest value to the list. How to append the complete set of values?

```
seq = [0, 1]

for n in range(2, 7):
    X = 2*seq[n - 1] + seq[n - 2]
    seq.append(X)

for num in seq:
    print(seq[num])
```

Comment: It is appending all the values. Change this `print(seq[num])` to this `print(num)`. You are iterating over the values of the list, not the indices.

Comment: Don't you get an error running this? What is the output you get and how did it lead you to your conclusion?

Comment: Thanks mate. It works fine. Silly things I miss

Answer (score 0):

Using this for-loop you can append the complete set of values.

```
for num in range(0,len(seq)):
    print(seq[num])
```